# Cancel or stop a $timeout in a recursive promise chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have a service which checks for item status every 3 seconds. If the item status is ready, then returns the status string. Otherwise, use `$timeout` to wait for 3 seconds and try again.

My problem is I'd like to cancel or stop the recursive timeout when user triggers some events(ex: leave the current page), but I don't know how to do that.

Service:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('ItemService', ItemService);

function ItemService($timeout, DataService) {
    var service = {
        checkStatus: checkStatus
    };

    function checkStatus() {
        return DataService.getItemStatus()
            .then(function(status){
                if (status === 'ready') {
                    return status;
                } else {
                    // the item is not ready. Check again after 3 seconds
                    return $timeout(function() {
                        return checkStatus();
                    }, 3000)
                }
            });
    }

}
```

Client:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ItemCtrl', ItemCtrl);

function ItemCtrl($scope, ItemService) {
    ItemService.checkStatus()
        .then(function(status) {
            // do somethin when item is ready.
        });

    $scope.$on('destroy', function(){
        // Should stop the $timeout recursive, but don't know how..
    });
}
```

Comment: You could probably attach a boolean value to certain event's and then in your status check, also check if one of the events was triggered

Comment: Ya that could solve the problem if there's only one item need to check. What if there're two items to be checked at the same page, and I'd like to stop only one of them sometimes?

Comment: I too have the same kind of problem, hoping to get an answer.

Comment: If `getItemStatus` is already returning a promise, why would it trigger a resolve before the status is actually ready?

Comment: @rgthre my `getItemStatus` is actually a GET request to a backend server, which will return the item status with a string `ready` or `processing` immediately, so it will resolve as long as the backend returns string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cancel an angular timeout with

```
$timeout.cancel(promise)
```

So something like this should work:

```
var promise = ItemService.checkStatus();
promise.then(function(status) {
        // do somethin when item is ready.
    });

$scope.$on('destroy', function(){
    if(typeof promise.then === 'function') {
        $timeout.cancel(promise);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that probably solves the problem, but it brings me another question: how can I check the if the promise in `destroy` function is a `$timeout` promise or not?

Comment: Good question - you should be safe just canceling the string if you'd like, but to check if it's a promise, I guess I would check to see if the object has a function called 'then' attached. I'll update my answer.

Comment: However, checking `then` function could not solve the problem because object returned by ready condition could be a promise, too.

Comment: You could check for the $$timeoutId field, which I believe is specific to Angular's timeout promises. This would at least ensure that it was an angular timeout, although it would not ensure it's the correct angular timeout.